# Android source code compile: failed to build some targets (03:03 (mm:ss))

Tags: android, ubuntu

These days, I am compiling the Android source code, but I have one problem, after running the `make -j8`, it shows me `failed to build some targets (03:03 (mm:ss))`.

Below is the detail informations:

> PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=Q
>
> PLATFORM_VERSION=Q
>
> TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_arm
>
> TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
>
> TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
>
> TARGET_ARCH=arm
>
> TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
>
> TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
>
> HOST_ARCH=x86_64
>
> HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
>
> HOST_OS=linux
>
> HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-34-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.1-LTS
>
> HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
>
> HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
>
> HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
>
> HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
>
> BUILD_ID=PI
>
> OUT_DIR=out
>
> ============================================
>
> [  0% 1/83585] Yacc: ss <= external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y
>   FAILED: out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.c
>   /bin/bash -c "prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/bison -d  --defines=out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.h -o out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.c external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y"
>   external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y: conflicts: 35 shift/reduce
>   prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/bison: m4 subprocess failed: No such file or directory
>   18:47:21 ninja failed with: exit status 1
>
> failed to build some targets (03:03 (mm:ss))

I hope someone can help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question to figure out what is failing.  But my guess is that it is caused by shift-reduce conflicts in the grammar in "ssfilter.y".

Answer (score 4):

the error message reads:

> m4 subprocess failed: No such file or directory

[m4](https://linux.die.net/man/1/m4) is a macro-processor - and the build fails as 0% already...

which makes me suspect, that `m4` isn't below the `PATH` - and no macros can be processed.

on Ubuntu `apt-get install m4` should install the package - or download `m4` from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/m4).

> GNU `m4` is an implementation of the traditional UNIX macro processor. It is mostly SVR4 compatible, although it has some extensions (for example, handling more than 9 positional parameters to macros).

it's difficult to refer to "credible and/or official sources"; except the manpages & source of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command and wait.

```
source build/envsetup.sh; lunch aosp_arm-eng; make -j8 ; source build/envsetup.sh; lunch sdk-eng; make sdk
```